# Show DateTimeOffset in View as normal Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want, that my DateTimeOffset in the database outputs in the View as a normal date (for example -> 10.12.2011). But it shows the date format like this -> 10.12.2011 12:30:30 +00:00.
I only want to change the dateformat in the view.

My ParticialView looks like this:

```
@foreach (var ShippedData in Model.ShippedData) {
    <tr>
      <td>@ShippedData.ReceiveDate.ToString()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

My Model like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
public DateTimeOffset? ReceiveDate { get; set; }
```

Wrong Output: 10.12.2011 12:30:30 +00:00

**Correct Output should be: 10.12.2011**

Comment: `@ShippedData.ReceiveDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString({PUT FORMAT HERE})`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks buddy. Actually kinda easy solution.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `ToString()` just returns the default formatting. You either need to use `DisplayFor` so that the `DisplayFormat` attribute will be utilized:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => ShippedData.ReceiveDate)
```

Or, include your desired formatting in `ToString`:

```
@ShippedData.ReceiveDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: How do I split my string which is a daterange for example:
Value of my string:
`"dd.MM.yyyy - dd.MM.yyyy"`

Comment: I used this here but it says that the array is out of the index range


`var dates = shippeddate.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var startDate = DateTime.Parse(dates[0]);
                var endDate = DateTime.Parse(dates[1]);`

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this to get Date section alone

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => ShippedData.ReceiveDate.Value.Date)
```